# Pipe Java2D Graphics drawings into multiple Graphics contexts

Tags: java, itext, java-2d

Does anyone know if there is way (maybe through an external API) to pipe Graphics drawings / transforms into multiple Graphics? The idea would be to save PNG and PDF at same time (using Java IText library).

Answer (score 1):

You could write the Graphics object to an (java, not iText) Image object. You can add java.awt.Image to iText using the following API calls:

- Image#getInstance(java.awt.Image, java.awt.Color)
- Image#getInstance(java.awt.Image, java.awt.Color, boolean)

Or you can output the image to a ByteArrayOutputStream and add the byte[] via these methods:

- Image#getInstance(byte[])
- Image#getInstance(byte[], boolean)

iText Image API: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the PDF functionality, but I assume that it stores the painted elements NOT as an image, but as some sort of vector graphics instead (based on the actual `Graphics#draw...` calls, similar to SVGGraphics2D from http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html ).

In any case, you should consider doing the `paint(g)` call twice, with different `Graphics` objects. The only alternative that I could imagine would be kind of ugly...

```
class MulticastGraphics2D extends Graphics2D {
    private List<Graphics2D> targets = new ArrayList<Graphics2D>();
    void allTarget(Graphics2D g) { targets.add(g); }
    void removeTarget(Graphics2D g) { targets.remove(g); }

    @Override
    public void drawLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
        for (Graphics2D target : targets) target.drawLine(x0,y0,x1,y1);
    }

    // + hundreds of further overridden methods....
}
```